# Browser adds "www.facebook.com/" image on every fb login in my WebApp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook-login

I'm using AngularJs 1.4 with ngFacebook module.
Why after every login Chrome browser adds new entry in "Resources -> Images"? What else should I do in my logout function? Currently I only clear localStorage, but do not call ngFacebook's logout. Doing the later will force the user to enter username/password again.

[image]

Comment: It's just a tracking pixel.  Do they persist if you reload the page?

Comment: no. if logged and reload the page then remains only one entry.

Comment: Facebook probably creates the pixel for every login attempt.  If you logout and log back in, it will create the pixel, but because that's only with every login attempt, it won't be very intensive on your page.  I'd say don't worry about the extra pixels it's creating.  It shouldn't really impact your application.

Comment: Should I have to reload login page after pressing "logout" button and after $location('/welcome');

Comment: I wouldn't think so.  The pixels can keep stacking.  The fact that they don't load all at the same time (they only load after a login/logout action by the end user) means that it won't be a performance issue.  I would just ignore them and let the facebook module do its thing.