# Browser adds the same facebook user avatar image in on every page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, facebook, facebook-graph-api, phaser-framework

I'm using AngularJs 1.4 with ngFacebook module. I have a similar issue which I have been convinced that can be ignored [more about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34814187/browser-adds-www-facebook-com-image-on-every-fb-login-in-my-webapp).
But the problem here (it had existed, but I didn't noticed it until now) is that avatars which I fetch during my App login process are progressively added to browser cache on each Back<->Forward click on browser's buttons after login. Here is example url: https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xla1/v/t1.0-1/c15.0.50.50/p50x50/1379841_10150004552801901_469209496895221757_n.jpg?oh=6bb0a02a85736c3eef0f79cc7f4f652e&oe=5701F533
(This is test user which no more exists) I show the upper full fb url for more clearance.

I just want to prevent accumulating of these images in browser cache.
And may be more important - How did you proceed in such cases, best practice, only using facebook login utilizing fb profile pictures as avatars in my WebApp?

Forgot to mention that I'm using Phaser framework where I load this avatar again, but it already exists in browser cache, because Angular based page already use it in my header bar. I'm confused about that.

PP: Refreshing through browser removes all.

[image: here is what I get]

Comment: _“I just want to prevent accumulating of these images in browser cache”_ – why? The browser should be able to handle its cache by itself, and there is usually no need to interfere with that.

Comment: Thank you very much. It helps me a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution - if you use fb login along with Phaser framework, and use fb user profile as avatar in both Phaser canvas game page and on some Angular page, then don't set this in Phaser preload stage:

```
this.game.load.crossOrigin = true;
```

Facebook has its own iframe based code to handle such COR issues.